# How to know if a smart contract is calling a function or if it is an EOA?

Tags: bytecode, selfdestruct, create2, eoa

Some have suggested detecting the contract bytecode size but this can be spoofed in the constructor where the value will be 0 for an EOA and a contract.

Then with create2 and self destruct the problem gets worse because then the attacker can perform multiple trxs.

Though I think if you just compare msg.sender == tx.origin a smart contract can never be the tx.origin thus you have your check. Let me know if that checks out : ).

Comment: Checking on `msg.sender == tx.origin` is the way to go but with account abstraction this check might be correct.